# Are Fifa 13 PC players matched against console players?

Tags: fifa-13

Are PC and console players matched together in multiplayer?

Comment: i don't know about Fifa 13 so i won't answer but no, Cross-platform doesn't happen. As game developers find the reward not befitting the work.

Comment: Not to mention that in some games (ie: First person shooters) console players are at a distinct disadvantage in comparison to PC gamers. Wouldn't be worth the tears.

Comment: I'm going to edit out the general question to avoid further tangents. I'm looking for an answer to Fifa 13.

Answer (score 3):

No, they are not matched together. Even in Ultimate Team, each platform has different markets.

There are also numerous issues of [cheating](http://forum.ea.com/uk/posts/list/2076734.page) on PC version.